# Random error "Laravel, Failed to authenticate on SMTP server"

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-7

My email setup works well and I can send emails from Laravel properly but sometimes randomly or when I want to send many emails at the same time, it fails and gives me this error:
"Laravel, Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using 3 possible authenticators, Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response"
How could I tackle this?
My code is simply:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new InfoEmail($user, $subject, $content, $cta_title, $cta_link));

// InfoEmail

    public function __construct($user, $subject, $content, $cta_title, $cta_link)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->subject = $subject;
    $this->content = $content;
    $this->cta_title = $cta_title;
    $this->cta_link = $cta_link;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('support@site.net', 'site')
        ->subject($this->subject . ' - site')
        ->view('mail.info')
        ->text('mail.info_plain');
}
```

Comment: Try enabling 2 step verification on you gmail account and use app password in your .env file instead of real credentials. Here's the [link](https://medium.com/graymatrix/using-gmail-smtp-server-to-send-email-in-laravel-91c0800f9662) . I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: @HassanMalik I already did both, not working.